# Ошибка с ListView при использовании ListActivity

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

Проблема с `ListView`.

Cтактрейс ошибки:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
>               at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
>               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1973)
>               at ru.neohorus.trains.FUC.onCreate(FUC.java:15)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
>                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Активность **FUC.class**:

```
public class FUCK extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fuc);
        ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list11);
        ArrayList<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();


        list.add(new Contact("09", "47", "Фр", "Я", "кр"));
        list.add(new Contact("14", "67", "Фр", "Ло", "кр"));

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.group_view,
                new String[] {Contact.TI, Contact.CO, Contact.NA, Contact.ST, Contact.HO}, new int[] {
                R.id.tex, R.id.te, R.id.tr, R.id.st, R.id.ho});
        list1.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
}
```

Разметка **fuc.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:divider="@color/list_divider"
          android:dividerHeight="3dp"
android:id="@+id/list11"
        >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

в стэктрейсе ясно сказано, что для того, чтобы `ListActivity` мог исполнять свои прямые обязанности, идентификатор `ListView` на разметке должен быть  `android.R.id.list` , у вас он `R.id.list11`

Кроме того, если вы используете `ListActivity`, то получать ссылку на `ListView` методом `findViewById()` совершенно излишне - активити сама найдет свой `ListView` по идентификатору `android.R.id.list`.

Так как `ListActivity` создан специально для работы с виджетом `ListView`, он реализует некоторые [дополнительные методы](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) , которые упрощают работу с виджетом и в этом случае код должен выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fuc);

    ArrayList<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    list.add(new Contact("09", "47", "Фр", "Я", "кр"));
    list.add(new Contact("14", "67", "Фр", "Ло", "кр"));

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                              this,
                              list,
                              R.layout.group_view,
                              new String[] {Contact.TI, Contact.CO, Contact.NA, Contact.ST, Contact.HO},
                              new int[] {R.id.tex, R.id.te, R.id.tr, R.id.st, R.id.ho});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Разметка:

```
<ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@android:id/list"/>
```