# Проблема с SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, sql

Помогите решить  проблему.
вот лог ошибки

```
08-05 14:49:05.400  11244-11244/com.example.greenstudio.forestinfo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.greenstudio.forestinfo/com.example.greenstudio.forestinfo.ActivityTwo}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:302)
        at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:168)
        at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:145)
        at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:91)
        at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:104)

        at com.example.greenstudio.forestinfo.ActivityTwo.onCreate(ActivityTwo.java:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)

        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

ActivityTwo.java

```
public class ActivityTwo extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    ListView list;
    DatabaseHelper sqlHelper;
    Cursor myCursor;
    sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SimpleCursorAdapter cAdapter;
    String[] from = new String[]{ DatabaseHelper.COLD_DOC_NAME};
    int[] to = new int[]{ R.id.ditext};
    setContentView(R.layout.docs);
    sqlHelper.create_db();
    try {
        sqlHelper.open();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
    myCursor = sqlHelper.database.rawQuery("select _id, doc_name from docs", null);
    cAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.ditem, myCursor, from, to, 0);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(cAdapter);
  }
 }
```

Спасибо, помогло добавление `_id` в запрос, но теперь возникла новая проблема:

> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.greenstudio.forestinfo/com.example.greenstudio.forestinfo.ActivityTwo}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Подозреваю что проблема в ссылке на несуществующий обект, то есть на столбец в базе

таблица в базе:

```
CREATE TABLE `docs` (
`_id`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`doc_type`  TEXT,
`doc_id`    TEXT,
`doc_name`  TEXT
```

);

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Обновил текст ActivityTwo.java, через дебагер обнаружил что ошибка вылазит при выполнении строчки

```
list.setAdapter(cAdapter);
```

причем list = null

Comment: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: @pavlofff, оформите ответом, если не сложно.

Comment: В бд то может быть и есть столбец ```_id``` , однако запрос, который выбирает данные из базы данных возвращает только столбец ```doc_name```. Думаю надо составить запрос следующим образом: ```"select _id," +  DatabaseHelper.COLD_DOC_NAME + " from " + DatabaseHelper.DOC_TABLE```

Comment: в случае `ListActivity` есть [определенные правила](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424449/177345). У вас они выполняются? В частности, нет нужды получать ссылку на `ListView` по `id`, а на разметке список должен содержать следующий идентификатор - `android:id="@android:id/list"`. Адаптер к списку привязывается методом `setListAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблема решена

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В БД [обязательно должен быть столбец](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192064/about-id-field-in-android-sqlite) `_id` с `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, для корректной работы классов android, связанных с SQLite